# $X$ is compact Hausdorff. Then ring automorphism $\mathcal C(X)\to \mathcal C(X)$ preserves norm.

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, general-topology

Consider $X$ a compact Hausdorff space. Suppose $\sigma:\mathcal C(X)\to\mathcal C(X)$ is a ring automorphism and $\Bbb C$-algebra or $\Bbb R$-algebra where $\mathcal C(X)$ denotes all continuous map from $X$ to real or complex numbers.

Due to completeness of $\Bbb R$ and $\Bbb C$, one endows sup norm on $\mathcal C(X)$ naturally.

The book asks to show $\sigma$ is norm preserving.

$\textbf{Q:}$ I do not know how to check $\sigma$ is norm preserving. I have considered the following. $(\mathcal C(X),\|\cdot\|_1)\to (\mathcal C(X),\|\cdot\|_2)$ with $\|\cdot\|_i$ norms, it suffices to consider pullback of closed unit ball from $\|\cdot\|_2$ and show $\|\cdot\|_1$'s unit sphere is sitting in. Then use symmetry to deduce this inducing the same topology. However, the norm might not be canonical as I have not seen the sup norm being the unique norm on $\mathcal C(X)$. (From the view of extension of absolute values on finite field extensions, my guess is that this might be true.) The other option is to look for $\mathcal C(X)\to \mathcal C(X)$ inducing "automorphism" $X\to X$ as in algebraic geometry via ring of functions identification. I have $\mathcal C(X)$ separating points at best but I do not see how to produce an homeomorphism of $X$ to itself. $\mathcal C(X)$ might not even be finitely generated. Any hint for suggestion on how to prove automorphism being norm preserving?

$\textbf{Q':}$ It seems that the statement is kind of implying there is 1 and only 1 norm on $\mathcal C(X)$ which is similar as finite field extension's absolute value for local fields. Is this correct?

Ref. Lang, Real and Functional Analysis Chpt 3, Exercise 12.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $\lambda \in f(X)$ if and only if $f-\lambda$ is not invertible, which happens if and only if $\sigma(f-\lambda)=\sigma(f)-\lambda$ is not  invertible. So $\sigma(f)(X)=f(X)$.

Comment: What is $\phi$?

Comment: @PaulFrost $\phi$ is $\sigma$ as indicated in the question

Comment: Maybe this is a dumb follow-up question. What is the classification of inequivalent norms for $C(X)$? Do I have one and only one norm?